# How to find all header files in directory and subdirectories in Windows

Tags: cmd, find, window, command-line-interface

i recently started working on windows operation system(2012 R2) and i am trying to find all files with header  format (*.h) in my directory and it subdirectories .

this how i got it when i ran in linux shell :

```
find /auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification -name "*.h"
```

i got the following results :

```
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/BlockStateMainProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/BlueFieldBdfProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/CfgLastIndexProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/CfgLastIndexPropertyProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/ComponentIsUpstreamProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/ConfigTraceProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/DmesgProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/DriverProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/HeaderLogProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/HotPlugProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/I1FrequencyProperty.h
/auto/sw_work/fwshared/ibrahims/git/svx/pci_verification/pci_properties/src/LinkEqProperty.h
```

how can i get the following results when running in windows command line?

thank in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an easy one.

The command to list files is `dir`. See `dir /?` for various switches.

```bat
dir /s /b "\auto\sw_work\fwshared\ibrahims\git\svx\pci_verification\*.h"
```

The `/s` switch looks recursive (including **s**ubfolders), the `/b` switch will show the files in **b**are format (no header, no summary, timestamps or size)

*Note: the directory separator in Windows is `\`, not `/` as in Unix/Linux.*